# Correct commit type for installing a dev dependency

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I'm trying to get started using semantic commit messages according to the Angular convention https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/22b96b9/CONTRIBUTING.md#-commit-message-guidelines
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QrDFcIiPjSLDn3EL15IJygNPiHORgU1_OOAqWjiDU5Y/edit#

But still can't find the right commit type when installing a new dependency in my project. In the end, it should end up like `<commit type>: install storybook`. What type should I use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since this commit changes the dependencies, the `build` type seems to be the most appropriate type.

Having said that, a commit that just adds a dependency without doing anything with it doesn't sound like a good idea, as it's not an atomic improvement to the codebase. In fact, that single commit worsens the codebase by adding an unused dependency. Instead, I'd create a larger commit that introduces the dependency and does something meaningful with it, meaning it will probably be a `feat` commit.

Comment: I agree, actually I mean to add storybook and a couple components to it in a react component library I'm building, but was struggling with the same, if that commit should be feat or build

Comment: @Khorne07 if you're just changing the dependencies, it's definitely a `build` commit. If you're adding new functionality and need to add dependencies to achieve it, it's probably a `feat` commit